# Hyperfast Recovery Diodes replacement

Tags: diodes, replacement

Can I replace one RHRP15120 diode with two U1560 DIODES IN SERIES used in an inverter filtering circuit without affecting the behavior of the circuit?

Comment: what circuit shud we expect?

Comment: Aha, the generic inverter filtering circuit raises its head yet again.

Answer (score 1):

An RHRP15120 diode has a PIV of 1200v. A U1560 has a PIV of 600v.

That means the replacement might be suitable in some circumstances, but not generally suitable.

If the 1200v diode is being used in a 700v application, then you may get away with 2x600v diodes. If it's being used at more than 900v, then you would be very ill advised to try. Somewhere in between? Are you feeling lucky, Punk?

The reason is that the diodes will not be matched. They will have different turn-off times, and different capacitance. As one diode starts to turn off when the other is still conducting, it will not be sharing the input voltage, but will have to support almost all of it. Adding a shunt capacitor across each diode will improve balancing, but increase the losses, which may or may not be important depending on the inverter frequency.

It is common to stack many diodes in series to achieve a higher PIV, with a typical derating of 50%. The idea is here that silicon diodes tend to fail short-circuit, so that when the fast switchers fail on the first application of power, they short, leaving a working stack. That approach doesn't really scale to a stack of two.

Answer (score 0):

Considering diode capacitance reduces with reverse voltage it will charge up faster, so if the series idea is to double the PIV rating, that wont fly.